# How do I call a a method which has MouseEventArgs?

Tags: c#, methods, dll, hook, mouse

I've been struggling with something for a while. I have a hook which detects mouse movement, and I can't call it repeatedly. It just gives me errors, I have no idea how to call it. Here's the code

```
private IKeyboardMouseEvents m_GlobalHook;

    public int x;
    public int y;



    public void Subscribe()
    {
        // Note: for the application hook, use the Hook.AppEvents() instead
        m_GlobalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents();

        m_GlobalHook.MouseDownExt += GlobalHookMouseDownExt;
        m_GlobalHook.KeyPress += GlobalHookKeyPress;
    }

    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        m_GlobalHook.MouseDownExt -= GlobalHookMouseDownExt;
        m_GlobalHook.KeyPress -= GlobalHookKeyPress;

        //It is recommened to dispose it
        m_GlobalHook.Dispose();
    }



    private bool mouseDown;
    private Point lastLocation;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    private void GlobalHookKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void GlobalHookMouseDownExt(object sender, MouseEventExtArgs e)
    {
        label7.Text = "IsDown: Yes";
        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y + trackBar1.Value);
        GlobalHookMouseDownExt; // This thing doesn't work, no matter if I use brackets or not to call it, it just doesn't work.
    }
```

Also, if I put in null, null. I get stackoverflowexception.

Comment: I think the event you're looking for is `MouseMove`. Right now you're only tracking mouse and keyboard click.

Comment: I'm looking for MouseDown, but outside the form. I use this thing called "GlobalMouseHook"

Comment: an event method is called when the event is activated... you to call this method you have to generate this event..

Comment: You say that "I have a hook which detects mouse movement". No you don't, you have a hook that detects the down part of the mouse click. So `GlobalHookMouseDownExt` should be being called when you click any button of the mouse. You can try this by putting a debug point inside the function and see if it's getting triggered when you use any mouse button. Also, calling `GlobalHookMouseDownExt` inside the function is a bad idea. You're getting `StackOverflowException` when putting null, null because you're calling the function recursively in an infinite loop..